# Kendo UI - Is it possible to target different styles per component?

Tags: css, grid, styles, kendo-ui

Is it possible to target different styles per component?    For example use the Silver style css for the menu and then the Default style css for the grid.

Comment: Maybe you can find answer in [kendo UI forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Place the menu inside an element with class "silver":

   ```
   <div class="silver">
       <!-- menu -->
   </div>
   ```
2. Modify **kendo.silver.css** by adding `.silver` in front of **every** CSS selector:

   ```
   .silver .k-block,
   .silver .k-widget,
   .silver .k-popup,
   .silver .k-content,
   .silver .k-dropdown .k-input
   /* the rest of kendo.silver.css */
   ```
3. Place the grid inside an element with class "default":

   ```
   <div class="default">
       <!-- grid -->
   </div>
   ```
4. Modify **kendo.default.css** by adding `.default` in front of **every** CSS selector:

   ```
   .default .k-block,
   .default .k-widget,
   .default .k-popup,
   .default .k-content,
   .default .k-dropdown .k-input
   /* the rest of kendo.default.css */
   ```

More info can be found in the [Kendo UI forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/setting-a-theme-on-individual-controls.aspx).